# JWT Authentication issue in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-web-api, jwt, asp.net-identity

I have attribute [Authorize] on my action. I tried to authenticate my user with JWT token but getting error 401.
[Error 401](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvQ9W.png)

**My Configuration**

```
using FluentValidation;
using FluentValidation.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
using Server.Api.Extensions;
using Server.Api.Middlewares;
using Server.Domain.Interfaces;
using Server.Domain.Services;
using Server.Infrastructure;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AveAnticaDbContextConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'AzureDbConnection' not found.");
ConfigurationManager configuration = builder.Configuration;

builder.Services.AddDbContext<AveAnticaDbContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));

builder.Services.AddControllers();


builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

builder.Services.AddFluentValidationAutoValidation();
builder.Services.AddValidatorsFromAssemblies(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());


builder.Services.AddScoped<IProductService, ProductService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IImageService, ImageService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICategoryService, CategoryService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ILanguageService, LanguageService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ITagService, TagService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ILikesService, LikesService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAccountService, AccountService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication();
builder.Services.ConfigureIdentity();
builder.Services.ConfigureJWT(builder.Configuration);

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

builder.Services.ConfigureSwagger();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseCors(options =>
{
    options.AllowAnyHeader();
    options.AllowAnyMethod();
    options.AllowAnyOrigin();
});

app.UseMiddleware<JwtTokenMiddleware>();
app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionMiddleware>();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

//app.UseResponseCaching();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

var directPath = "Uploads";//builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Path");
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
           Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, directPath)),
    RequestPath = "/" + directPath
});

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

**Configuration extensions**

```
public static class ServiceExtension
    {
        public static void ConfigureIdentity(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var builder = services.AddIdentity<Customer, IdentityRole>(o =>
            {
                o.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                o.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                o.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                o.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                o.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AveAnticaDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        }

        public static void ConfigureJWT(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            var jwtConfig = configuration.GetSection("JwtOptions");
            var secretKey = jwtConfig["Key"];
            services.AddAuthentication(opt =>
            {
                opt.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = jwtConfig["Issuer"],
                    ValidAudience = jwtConfig["Audience"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey))
                };
            });
        }
        public static void ConfigureSwagger(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSwaggerGen(option =>
            {
                option.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Demo API", Version = "v1" });
                option.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Description = "Please enter a valid token",
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
                    BearerFormat = "JWT",
                    Scheme = "Bearer"
                });
                option.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                {
                    {
                        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                        {
                            Reference = new OpenApiReference
                            {
                                Type=ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                                Id="Bearer"
                            }
                        },
                        new string[]{}
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

**My Account Service(Only functions that relates to token generation)**

```
public async Task<string> CreateTokenAsync(Customer user)
        {
            var signingCredentials = GetSigningCredentials();
            var claims = await GetClaims(user);
            var tokenOptions = GenerateTokenOptions(signingCredentials, claims);
            return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(tokenOptions);
        }

        private SigningCredentials GetSigningCredentials()
        {
            var jwtConfig = configuration.GetSection("JwtOptions");
            var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jwtConfig["Key"]);
            var secret = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key);
            return new SigningCredentials(secret, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
        }

        private async Task<List<Claim>> GetClaims(Customer user)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName)
                };
            var roles = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
            foreach (var role in roles)
            {
                claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
            }
            return claims;
        }
```

**JWT Options**

```
  "JwtOptions": {
    "Issuer": "AveAntica",
    "Lifetime": 12,
    "Audience": "AveAnticaAudience",
    "Key": "1234234rearaeta4wa4rras4tra"
  },
```

Also, you can visit my repository for more information:[Repository](https://github.com/GeorgiyGit/AveAntica)

I tried different configurations. Also
it doesn't matter if i use [Authorize] or [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)].

I know, that my token is delivered to the server and it is normal, at least decoded on some sites.

I download another project with +-similar code and similar configurations. It works correctly(I also checked and update nugets, it doesn`t changes the situation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your GenerateTokenOptions()
:

Try to change  `audience: jwtSettings["Issuer"],` into `audience: jwtSettings["Audience"],`

Comment: thank you, i think my problem consisted of two parts, and you help me with one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I have answer. I tried to remove some nugets, and after removing 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens' it start works. Of course, audience: jwtSettings["Audience"] may also helped me with it.